# Not able to create package in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

While creating packages in oracle it is asking for previlage.. what shall i do..

I tried

```
 SQL> GRANT CREATE PACKAGE TO C##SA ;
```

showing error

```
GRANT CREATE PACKAGE TO C##SA
      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00990: missing or invalid privilege
```

Comment: You should learn to use the documentation.  You could easily have answered this for yourself.  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9013.htm#SQLRF01603

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  GRANT CREATE any procedure TO C##SA ;
```

---

You can try these below views.

```
SELECT * FROM USER_SYS_PRIVS; 
SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_PRIVS;
SELECT * FROM USER_ROLE_PRIVS;
```

Comment: It only needs to be CREATE PROCEDURE.  We should avoid granting `ANY` level privileges unless the user really needs the power to affect other schemas.

Answer (score 4):

It is

```
create (any) procedure
```

Privileges:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21642/privileges.htm#TTSQL340

Answer (score 0):

grant create session, create procedure to user identified by user;

```
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9532924000346535486
```

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9532924000346535486